# Can I get information on an S3 Bucket's public access bucket Settings from boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 to extract information about my S3 buckets.
However, I am stuck at this point. I am trying to extract information about a bucket's public access (see attached screenshot).

How can I get this information? So far I have failed to find out any boto3 function that allows me to do so.

[image]

Comment: I suspect those settings are actually just a user-friendly presentation of something lower level, such as attaching a managed Policy to the bucket. If so, there won't be a function that shows them as a boolean, you'll need to find what they do "underneath".

Comment: @IMSoP Hmm. Tha's a bummer. The same information exists for `S3 access points`. Pity that it does not for the bucket as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_public_access_block()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_public_access_block):

> Retrieves the `PublicAccessBlock` configuration for an Amazon S3 bucket.
>
> When Amazon S3 evaluates the `PublicAccessBlock` configuration for a bucket or an object, it checks the `PublicAccessBlock` configuration for both the bucket (or the bucket that contains the object) and the bucket owner's account. If the `PublicAccessBlock` settings are different between the bucket and the account, Amazon S3 uses the most restrictive combination of the bucket-level and account-level settings.

If you wish to modify the settings, you can use: [`put_public_access_block()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_public_access_block)

Comment: This is works like golden! Thank you, John!